# How do I recover a previous version of a page layout?

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, visualforce, force.com

I modified a page layout in our QA environment using Apex and didn't refresh from the server (my last refresh from the server was 10 days ago). Someone else made a TON of changes using the web interface in between then. I just overwrote all of her changes!

Does anyone have any advice on how I can undo my changes and go back to hers?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there's no tracking of layout changes so there's no way you can just revert this — are there any other developers who may have had a later copy of the metadata and haven't refreshed theirs yet?

It can be a good idea to use ANT to run a metadata backup system so that things like this don't cause problems :) [There's a guide to using the Force.com Deployment Tool here](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Migration_Tool_Guide), essentially you just want to use half of that process on a regular schedule.

Comment: Hey Matt- thanks for the reply. Was on the phone with SF support and they said that i was up a creek. Can you tell me about ANT? Sooo stressed from this...

Comment: every day or so I pull down all of the meta data and commit it to SVN.  It's a GREAT idea to do this to prevent exactly these kinds of things from happening.